# UINavigationController navigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I use UINavigation controller and have a question. Is there way to switch from **third view** to **first view**?
Method where I create new object `FirstView *controller; [self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:controller animated:YES];` is not suitable for me (losing transfered data from parent to first view).

[image: enter image descriptrtrt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this . it will work.

You can get all the View controllers in an array and pop to a specific view controller
. This code will pop to your FirstView Controller.

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Comment: This won't pop you to the first viewController... the first viewController is the `rootViewController` which is at index 0.

Comment: @Paul.s ParentView will be at index 0, FirstView at index 1, SecondView at index 2 ...

Comment: No that is this misunderstanding/incorrect terminology of the original poster. The parent (container) view is the navigationController which contains an array of content views.

Comment: @Paul.s According to RomanHouse diagram Parentview is the rootviewcontroller .

Comment: Like I said the original poster has his terminology wrong, which doesn't mean the accepted answer needs to follow suit... or anyone in future looking for a similar solution will get the wrong idea as well

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you know your view controller to return to and it is stored in `returnToViewController`:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:retunToViewContoller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Again the same, to do this I will be need to create `FirstView *returnToViewController` but in this case I lose my data in ***first view***

Comment: @RomanHouse, no you wont. Your FirstView controller is already on the navigation stack. You are not supposed to create it again. The navigation controller keeps them in an array and you only navigate the structure back.

Comment: Why should you loose any data? If you do then you have made any other mistake that is not really related to the push and pop mechanism of navigation controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to go back one view controller; or:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to go back to the very first view controller in the hierarchy.

Comment: `[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` will return me to `Second View` and `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` will return to `Parent View`..